# Why is the lib directory in Rails not in the autoload path by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload

I know the `lib/` directory can be added to the `autoload_paths` and `eager_load_paths` quite easily. But I don't quite understand why files in `lib/` are not autoloaded or eager loaded by default?

I can't find a simple answer anywhere unfortunately so I'd really appreciate if someone could explain this to me simply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is no Rails convention for putting files in `lib` that require autoloading. `lib` is for rake/thor tasks which reside `lib/tasks` and little else.

Your application-specific files should go in `app`. If you find yourself thinking of putting something in `lib`, it probably belongs somewhere in `app`, or in a Gem.

Comment: Anything under `app` will be autoloaded. You can use `app/lib` for things which don't fit into the default directories, or make up a new directory. For example, I put service objects into `app/services`.